# Erro classse R, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Após criar um projeto no Android Studio,  aparece o seguinte erro no console:

```
/home/nayron/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2 /app/build       /intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/nayron/android-sdks/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Poderiam me explicar os possíveis motivos desse erro e como soluciona-lo, por favor?

Comment: Nayron, poderia incluir o seu `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

Este erro, em se tratandop de Android Studio, pode ter muitas causas.

Dando uma rapida pesquisada na internet percebe-se inúmeras pssoas com o mesmo erro e causas e soluções diferentes.

Uma delas é fazer o Downgrade do Gradle para a versão  `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3` ou o Upgrade para versão mais recente.

Comment: Tentei fazer o que me recomendou, mas não obtive sucesso. O erro persiste.

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @NayronMorais você esta usando o 'Gradle'?

Comment: Eu acho que o erro é porque ele está usando a versão 23 do `apocopam` mas não está usando o `compileSdkVersion` na versão 23.

Comment: Sou leigo nesta área, não sei se estou usando-o.